# How can I Set State of a Value that is inside some other Function

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, clarifai

I am Trying to Create a React App That Detects Age of Pictures Using Clarifai API .
I am Able to Console.Log Detected Age but I Want To Display The Age on My Webpage . Help me With Setting The AgeDectect State so I Can Use it on my Webpage

```
             //Value Displayed On Console
              //39
```

​

```
            //App.js Code That Console.Logs Age
              class App extends Component {
            constructor(){
             super();
             this.state = {
             input : '',
             imgURL : '',
             AgeDetect : ''
             }
            }

            onInputChange = (event) => {
              this.setState({input : event.target.value});
             }

            onClickEvent = () => {
              this.setState({imgURL : this.state.input})

              app.models.predict(Clarifai.DEMOGRAPHICS_MODEL ,
                                 this.state.input).then(
                      function(response) {
                           const A =response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].
                                  data.face.age_appearance.concepts[0].name
             //This Line of Code Displays Age on Console 
                                  console.log(A);
                                  this.setState({AgeDetect : A});
                             },
          //Having Problem SettingState ,this.state.AgeDetect isnt
                                                //doing anything
         render(){
                return (<AgeDetection AgeDetect={this.state.AgeDetect}/>
                      )
                   }
             //AgeDetection.js file      
      import React from 'react' ; 
      const AgeDetection = ({AgeDetect}) => {
      return(       
             <div>
              {AgeDetect}
             </div>
           );
         }
         export default AgeDetection;
```

Comment: You could propably just write a script that inserts the data into an html div that looks something like:   document.write('<div class="data"><h4>Data</h4><ul> ' +  listOfData + '</ul></div>');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort your array that is returned by the value and set the first object or the whole array to your state and then you can use it in your app very easily.  Use an arrow function inside your predict then block to bind to the class.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      input: '',
      imgURL: '',
      AgeDetect: ''
    };
  }
  onInputChange = event => {
    this.setState({ input: event.target.value });
  };

  onClickEvent = () => {
    this.setState({ imgURL: this.state.input });
    app.models.predict(Clarifai.DEMOGRAPHICS_MODEL, this.state.input).then(
      response => {
        const A =
          response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].data.face.age_appearance
            .concepts[0].name;

        this.setState({ AgeDetect: A });
      },
      function(err) {
        // there was an error
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <Navigation />
        <Logo />
        <ImageLinkForm
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          onClickEvent={this.onClickEvent}
        />
        <FaceRecognition imgURL={this.state.imgURL} />
        <AgeDetection AgeDetect={this.state.AgeDetect} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: I Filtered My Console.Log to only Array[0].name (i.e : Age Displayed by 0th Element of Array ) . How Can I display that only Item on my Webpage

Comment: Not sure what you mean.  Sort the array and then set a value to the state.  If its just the name that you want then set just the name to a value in the state. After that you can use that state value anywhere in your component.  Lets say you set the value to `myValue` in your state.  Then you can do something like `<div>{this.state.myValue}</div>` anwhere in your components jsx

Comment: const A = response.outputs[0].data.regions[0].data.face.age_appearance.concepts[0].name //outputs a number (which is age i want to display ) . Then this.setState=({AgeDetect : A }) . This State returns me an empty value

Comment: If A has a valid output then setting that output the state should work.  I'm not sure what you are doing.  Here is a simple example of this working https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-surf-rcdkc

Comment: Now how are you trying to display it in your page this part looks fine.

Comment: using this line of code in render function <AgeDetection AgeDetect={this.state.AgeDetect}/> . And in using these lines of code in AgeDectection.js file .. import React from 'react' ;

const AgeDetection = ({AgeDetect}) => {
    return(

     <div>
         {AgeDetect}
     </div>
       
    );
}
export default AgeDetection;

Comment: I'm not sure it may have something to do with the function your running it in but it doesn't seem likely.  Idk what to tell you just from what I can see it should be working.  Without being able to see your code and debug it myself its hard to see what the problem is.  Is imgURL being added to the state properly inside your onClickEvent?  You can maybe try using lower case letters and renaming things.

Comment: onClickEvent is working properly as my .then(function.....  console.logs the age , I think I am not able to setstate because the Function in which in I am setting state lies inside onClickEvent Function , here is link to full code and app :https://github.com/cyumair/smartbrain

Comment: Use an arrow function to bind the function to the class then you can set the state.  I edited my answer to show this.

Comment: Displays Age in the console , not on webpage ... And on 2nd click displays TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: Its working for me I downloaded your code and it works fine.  I edited the answer again with what I have here just copy it and let me know.  I am console logging the state as well to show the state change.  I took the particles out though.